# MongoDB query fails with NoQueryExecutionPlans

Tags: mongodb

Executing the following query in MongoDB

```
db.getCollection("translations").find({namespace: "public_frontend"})
```

leads to the following error

```
Query failed with error code 291 and error message 'error processing query: ns=i18n_api.translations batchSize=21Tree: namespace $eq "public_frontend" Sort: {} Proj: {} planner returned error :: caused by :: No indexed plans available, and running with 'notablescan'' on server
```

The collection has the following indexes:

```
[
    {
        "v" : 2.0,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1.0
        },
        "name" : "_id_"
    },
    {
        "v" : 2.0,
        "key" : {
            "key" : 1.0,
            "namespace" : 1.0
        },
        "name" : "key_1_namespace_1",
        "unique" : true,
        "sparse" : true
    }
]
```

Comment: If you add an index on only `"namespace"`, does your query complete without error?

Comment: Is `transations` a view by chance? Edit: oh, after re-reading, @rickhg12hs is definitely correct. MongoDB will use an index when the _first_ field is part of the query. But you aren't using the first indexed field (`key`) in that query

Comment: Weird, but when I added an index only for namespace, the query completed without error. However, after removing the index, the query still passed. I think this might have to do with invalid plan cache that was cleared after the query completed successfully.

Answer (score 1):

As per requested by @IsmaelVacco Indexes are data structures that support the efficient execution of queries in MongoDB. In order to use the geospatial query in MongoDB you need to create a 2d sphere index on the field which contains that set of latitude and longitude. You can do that by first selecting the database on which you want to create that index then going onto the index tab and then add an index of 2d sphere to field which has those latitude and longitude.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you please add more details or information to your answer? That helps others to understand better.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: As per requested by @IsmaelVacco Indexes are data structures that support the efficient execution of queries in MongoDB. In order to use the geospatial query in MongoDB you need to create a 2d sphere index on the field which contains that set of latitude and longitude. You can do that by first selecting the database on which you want to create that index then going onto the index tab and then add an index of 2d sphere to field which has those latitude and longitude